# Conditionally displaying parts of my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say I have an asp.net mvc website with a page that lists products. ON that page I have a "delete" button that should only show up for the user that inserted the product. What's the best way to do this?

One way I thought of doing it was setting a boolean in the controller to let the view know if the button should be displayed. Something like:

```
if(IsProductOwner(UserId))
    ViewData["CanDelete"] = true;
```

Then in the view I can just do

```
<% if((boolean)ViewData["CanDelete"] == true) { %>
    // show delete button
<% } %>
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought is that you should at least make that a function of the Product class so you can go:

```
<% if (product.IsOwnedBy(UserId)) { %>
    // show delete button
<% } %>
```

This removes some of the floaty ViewData and builds the business logic into your classes rather than floating out on the edges.

However, I haven't found a decent way to do this sort of conditional display in views unless the view is significantly different then I get the action to display a different view depending on the context.

Comment: On one hand I really like your approach as it's very clean. However, since it's a list of products on the page that means every product will require a database hit. 50 products = 50 database roundtrips. Interestingly enough, all the products listed on a page will be from the same user. So this makes me lean towards the original solution of adding a ViewData["CanDelete"] (which I still don't like) :)

Comment: Well I'm imagining your product holds against it which user owns it so you would already have that information and no round-trip would be required. Depends on how your system is structured I suppose.

Comment: Actually you are right! Ok this is the solution I will go with. Thanks!

Comment: ok, after spending much of my day refactoring my code it looks like this is the best way to go. ssg's solution works great if all the products are by the same user. but once you mix up products from different users this solution works best